# How can a plant grow in a refrigerator?

Tags: wall-e

In the [2008 movie WALL-E](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910970/), we see the WALL-E robot rummaging through some trash early in the movie. It comes across an old refrigerator which it cannot open via normal means, so it cuts it open.

Inside the refrigerator we see a small plant growing. Plants require light, fresh air, and water to grow: none of which are available inside of a closed refrigerator sealed so tight it had to be cut open.

How did the plant grow inside of a closed refrigerator?

Comment: I always knew the light stayed on when I closed the door!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The simplest answer is that the plant **wasn't sealed inside the fridge**. It was **next to the fridge**.

As you can see from the frame before, the door had fallen off the fridge and was blocking Wall-E's way.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A lot of plants start their life from a seed, root cutting or bulb that is underground until the sprout breaks through to the surface, while there is water there is not much light and little air there :) This is limited by the resources the seed etc. brings along, but this is something that you could stretch a bit in a fictional universe... and for example, if you leave a bunch of spring onions on the shelf they tend to grow new leaves even when not watered and when exposed to indoor-only amounts of light...